# Why is my request in Python not registered by the server?

Tags: python, httprequest, matomo

I am currently writing a script in Python which allows to listen the serial port from a connected device in order to guess the height of a person when passing through a door.
The final idea is to send this information to Piwik, a web analytics package through a http request.
The code is as follow:

```
import serial, httplib, uuid
arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
while True:
    data = arduino.readline()
    print data
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("my-domain.com")
    conn.request("HEAD","/piwik/piwik.php?idsite=1&rec=1&action_name=Entree-magasin&uid="+str(uuid.uuid4())+"&e_c=entree-magasin&e_a=passage&e_n=taille&e_v="+str(data)+"")
    print conn.request
```

when I just ask to print the following line:

```
"/piwik/piwik.php?idsite=1&rec=1&action_name=Entree-magasin&uid="+str(uuid.uuid4())+"&e_c=entree-magasin&e_a=passage&e_n=taille&e_v="+str(data)+""
```

it works fine. But if I look in the logs of the server hosting my website the request is not sent.
If I remove the following part `"&e_c=entree-magasin&e_a=passage&e_n=taille&e_v="+str(data)+"` then it works fine and the request is sent.
If I leave the following part `&e_c=entree-magasin&e_a=passage&e_n=taille&e_v="+str(data)+"` and hard code the following value `+str(data)+` by a figure, then the request is sent too.

I don't really where the problem can be. If anyone can help that would be great.

After reading your answers and work on and on on it, I find a way of optimizing my code by using the requests function instead, but the result is still the same i cannot get str(data) value within my request:

`import serial, requests, uuid
arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
while True:
    data = arduino.readline()
    print data
    r = requests.get('http://my-domain.com/piwik/piwik.php?idsite=1&rec=1&action_name=Entree-magasin&uid='+str(uuid.uuid4())+'&e_c=entree-magasin&e_a=passage&e_n=taille&e_v='+str(data)+'')
    print r`

Comment: It seems it depends on the cast of `data` into a string. So what is data? And can the resulting string be concatenated with other strings?

Comment: data is a range figure between 205 and 100.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, the parameters are not part of header

```
resp, content = h.request("http://my-domain.com/piwik/piwik.php?idsite=1&rec=1&action_name=Entree-magasin&uid="+str(uuid.uuid4())+"&e_c=entree-magasin&e_a=passage&e_n=taille&e_v="+str(data), "GET")
```

Comment: not sure I got it right, does it mean that my final code is: https://gist.github.com/NanorPiwik/bbebe1b9e7837df89ad2#file-my-http-request-issue I tried it with different configurations and got several errors either through h or request which are not defined or resp or content

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I tried to do the same thing but with Google Analytics instead of Piwik. It works with Google Analytics, the str(data) is going back properly within the system, but for some reason it is not working with Piwik :(